# Getting Error: CSRF token mismatch in laravel 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to submit a form in laravel using ajax, which has some input types and upload file option. After submit a form, i got a error -

```
{message: "CSRF token mismatch.", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"file: "D:\development\laravel\parangatcrm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php"line: 389message: "CSRF token mismatch."

I have added this in my blade file -
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> 
<input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

This is my ajax code - 
$.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'PATCH',
                    data: new FormData($("#formId")[0]),
                    cache : false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (res){
                        console.log(res);
                    }
                    ,error: function (err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the csrf token on header, not with the form data. try something like this on your code:

To add a default header with every request, use $.ajaxSetup():

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
```

or else you can add the header like below code:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': ('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
                        type: 'PATCH',
                        data: new FormData($("#formId")[0]),
                        cache : false,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (res){
                            console.log(res);
                        }
                        ,error: function (err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Now error is coming -  "The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

Comment: Check your web route. You most likely defined the URL as a GET url

Comment: Route was defined as patch.. Now i have changed the method and route as post.. Now code is working fine. Thanx @zihad

Comment: I got it now after you you explained your scenario. To make LARAVEL Patch URL working, You need to send the request as POST and pass a hidden input _method with a value 'PATCH' i.e.   place this inside your form  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">